# I want to create a Ruby on Rails Temporary Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, temp-tables

I have multiple arrays in my Ruby on Rails controller that look like this:

```
@array1 = {"artist_id"=>10896479,"events" => ["event1, event2, event3"]}
@array2 = {"artist_id"=>14566479,"events" => ["event4, event5, event6"]}
```

I want to iterate through each array, grab each event such as "event1" and "event2" and put them into a temporary table so I get an events column with "event1, event2, event3, event4, event5, event6" that I can organize and print out onto an html table.  How would I go about doing that? Sample code snippets would really help since I am fairly new to Ruby on Rails.  My goal is grab the events from all these different artists and list them out on a table sorted in the order of which events are coming the soonest.

Comment: How much code like this do you have in your file? Would it be easy to copy these lines into a text editor and convert them into `INSERT` statements?

Comment: I ended up using the ActiveRecord library to make a temporary table.  Thanks for the comments though!  @muistooshort I had to organize data from different tables with different fields into one "feed" area.  I am not the most optimized programmer so I do not know the best ways to do this, but creating a temporary table seemed like a good way to organize information so it can be sorted for a feed.

Comment: @robotsandwizards could you please post your solution? i'm trying to do something similar.